# jQuery blur() and click()

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery functions:

1. Submits the form

   $(".content").delegate('.entryButton','click', function() {
   var form = $(this).closest("form");
   var id = form.attr('id');
   var text = form.find("textarea").val();
   Sijax.request('add_entry', [id, text]);

   ```
        //Prevent the form from being submitted (default HTML)
        return false;
    });
   ```
2. Enlarge the form and show the entry button

   $("textarea").focus(function() {
   $(this).css('height', '80px');
   var button = $(this).parent().next().children();
   button.css('visibility', 'visible');
   button.css('height', '20px')
   });
3. Makes the textarea smaller and hides the button

   $("textarea").blur(function() {
   $(this).css('height', '30px');
   var button = $(this).parent().next().children();
   button.css('height', '0px')
   });

This happens when I try to make an entry:

- Click in the field (focus event), the field grows larger and shows the entry button
- Enter text
- Click on the entry button first time: **Now the blur event fires which makes the field smaller again but the click event doesn't fire**
- If I click the button again the form does submit

I think this means the blur and click event interfere with each other?

**You can find a fiddle of the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2nUba/).** When you press the button with the field focused, it blurs the field but doesn't enter it. When you press the button with the field blurred the entry does get submitted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you set up a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.entryButton').on('click', function (e) {
    return false; // to prevent default form post
});
$("form").delegate('.entryButton','mousedown', function() {
    $('textarea').trigger('blur');
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    var id = form.attr('id');
    var text = form.find("textarea").val();
    $("#test").append(text);                 

    //Prevent the form from being submitted (default HTML)
    return false;
});
```

and keep the focus and blur function as before.

```
thanks.
```

Comment: please see my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896084/jquery-ajax-on-focusout-on-submit-requires-2-clicks

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `click` fires on the button on `mouseup`, however when you change the height, that makes it to where your mouse is no longer on the button when the `mouseup` happens. Use `mousedown` instead of `click` and then `trigger('blur')` on the `textarea` to make both events happen.

Note: you still need a `click` event in there just so you can `return false` to cancel out the default form submission functions.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/yUhkC/1/)

Comment: You don't need to `trigger` the blur - change the return false to a `preventDefault` and blur will fire.

Comment: I tried that initially, but the textarea's `blur` event doesn't fire on button click without the `trigger()`. (The textarea still has the blue focus highlight around it after clicking the button). Also, you're preventing default action on `click`, not on `mousedown`, so in this case you need both events.

Comment: You're correct about needing both events, however, that makes having the `return false` in the mousedown pointless.

Comment: True.  The `return false` in the `mousedown` function was in the original fiddle and I neglected to remove it. (updated fiddle link)

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem is the `blur` event, which works faster than the `click` event. That is why it makes the field smaller instead of submitting the form first.

You only need to change the first line from `click` to `mousedown`:

```
$(".content").delegate('.entryButton','mousedown', function() {
// your code
});
```

Or:

```
$(".content").bind('mousedown', function() {
// your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found myself comfortable to use http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like changing the height and forcing a reflow cancels the click event. The easiest solutions are either to use `mousedown` rather than click (it fires before blur) or wrap the css change in a `setTimeout`.