# Jquery Ajax On-Focusout On-Submit - Requires 2 Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I have a jquery and ajax validation form, when you fill the values (wrong values) x@x.com and 1111111 in password it will give ajax validation notice (which is fine) but after that if you put in the values (correct values) example@example.com and 12345678 it requires two clicks to submit. Meaning if you put wrong values first and then put correct values then it will require two clicks to submit. following is the code. I have set the code below so you can copy and paste the code into files (filenames given before) and you will have a working model to work with.  I have hardcoded the php validate file so you guys can copy and paste the code and see how it works.

index.php

```
<?php 
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" name="loginform" action="success.php">
        <input type="email" class="homepage"  name="user_email2" id="user_email2" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50" required />
        <div class ="errormsg" id ="errormsg6"></div>
        <input type="password" class="homepage"  name="user_password2" id="user_password2" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" required />
        <div class ="errormsg" id ="errormsg7"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Submit">
        <div class ="errormsglast" id ="errormsg8"></div>

    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validatelogin.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

validatelogin.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* ----------------- Login Validations Global Variables -----------------   */
    var user_email2 = "";
    var user_emailajax2 = "";
    var user_password2 = "";
    var user_passwordajax2 = "";
    var emailformat = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);

    /* ----------------- Define Validate Email */
    var validate_email_login = function()
    {
        var item5 = $("#user_email2").val();
        var item5 = item5.toLowerCase();
        if (item5.length < 6 || item5.length > 50)
        {
            $("#errormsg6").html("Email : 6 - 50 Characters");
            user_email2 = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errormsg6").html("");
            user_email2 = item5;
            if (!emailformat.test(item5))
            {
                $("#errormsg6").html("Wrong Email Format");
                user_email2 = "";
            }
            else
            {
                $("#errormsg6").html("");
                user_email2 = item5;
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'validatelogin.php?f=1',
                    data: "user_email2=" + item5,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        if (msg == "ok")
                        {
                            user_emailajax2 = "";
                            $("#errormsg6").html("Email Does Not Exist");
                        }
                        else if (msg == "exists")
                        {
                            user_emailajax2 = item5;
                            $("#errormsg6").html("");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    /* ----------------- Define Validate Password */
    var validate_password_login = function()
    {
        var item5 = $("#user_email2").val();
        var item5 = item5.toLowerCase();
        var item6 = $("#user_password2").val();

        if (item6.length < 8 || item6.length > 20)
        {
            $("#errormsg7").html("Password : 8-20 Characters");
            user_password2 = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errormsg7").html("");
            user_password2 = item6;
            if (user_email2 != "" && user_emailajax2 != "")
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "validatelogin.php?f=2",
                    data: "user_email2=" + item5 + "&user_password2=" + item6,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        if (msg == "WrongPw")
                        {
                            user_passwordajax2 = "";
                            $("#errormsg7").html("Wrong Password");
                        }
                        else if (msg == "CorrectPw")
                        {
                            user_passwordajax2 = item6;
                            $("#errormsg7").html("");
                            /* window.location.href="manage-properties"; */
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    /* ----------------- Run Functions */
    $("#user_email2").on('focusout', validate_email_login);
    $("#user_password2").on('focusout', validate_password_login);
    $("#login").on('click', validate_email_login);
    $("#login").on('click', validate_password_login);

    /* ----------------- Stop on Submit */
    $("#login").on('click', function()
    {
        if (user_email2 == "" || user_emailajax2 == "" || user_password2 == "" || user_passwordajax2 == "")
        {
            $("#errormsg8").html("Please Fill All Fields (Correctly)");
            console.log("submit false");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errormsg8").html("");
            console.log("submit true");
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

validatelogin.php

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if($_GET['f']==1) {
    if(isset($_POST['user_email2'])) {
        $user_email2 = strtolower($_POST['user_email2']);
        if($user_email2 == "example@example.com") {
            echo "exists";
        } else {
            echo "ok";  
        } 
    }
}

if($_GET['f']==2) { 
    if(isset($_POST['user_email2'], $_POST['user_password2'] )) {
        $user_email2 = strtolower($_POST['user_email2']);
        $user_password2 = $_POST['user_password2']; 

        if($user_email2!="example@example.com" and $user_password2!="12345678") {
            echo "WrongPw";
        } elseif($user_email2=="example@example.com" and $user_password2=="12345678") {
            echo "CorrectPw";
        }
    }
}   
?>
```

success.php

```
<?php
echo "Login Successful";
?>
```

**Tried Solutions**
1. Putting a delay on the submit button
2. On Keyup instead of on Focusout (this works but not what is required)
3. Give delay to keyup (could not get it to work with ajax - but its closer to what I require, but not exactly what I require
4. Triggering the click on submit on return true of ajax (also did not work)

I need some javascript expert to look into it and give me solution.

Comment: $("#user_email2").on('focusout', validate_email_login);
    $("#user_password2").on('focusout', validate_password_login); 
    //$("#login").on('click', validate_email_login);
   // $("#login").on('click', validate_password_login);, you are calling two times here!!!!!!, post your form in the onlclick event of your submit button once. And validate your fields while submitting or use jquery validation to validate at the client side. Please refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't want to be rude, but all that code is a bit of a disaster. You're calling the on click function 3 different times, you're making ajax calls to the server on every form change and on submit. Then you're actually making two separate ajax calls for the actual submit function.

The code below is a lot more compact, only ever makes one ajax call and should work. I'll explain a bit before each code block

Your form add an id so that jQuery can use serialize in the ajax call

```
<form method="post" id="loginform" name="loginform" action="success.php">
    <input type="email" class="homepage"  name="user_email2" id="user_email2" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50" required />
    <div class ="errormsg" id ="errormsg6"></div>
    <input type="password" class="homepage"  name="user_password2" id="user_password2" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" required />
    <div class ="errormsg" id ="errormsg7"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Submit">
    <div class ="errormsglast" id ="errormsg8"></div>

</form>
```

**validatelogin.php** - This should only be one call to the server, do both functions in one, return the data as json rather than echoing single values, that way you get an object back that you can parse in your jQuery code.

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if(isset($_POST['user_email2'], $_POST['user_password2'] )) {
    $user_password2 = $_POST['user_password2']; 
    $user_email2 = strtolower($_POST['user_email2']);
    if($user_email2 != "example@example.com") {
        $data['email_check'] = 'false';
    } else {
        $data['email_check'] = 'true';
    } 
    $data = array;
    if($user_email2!="example@example.com" && $user_password2!="12345678") {
        $data['password_check'] = 'false';
    } else {
        $data['password_check'] = 'true';
    }
}
print(json_encode($data));
```

**jQuery** - I am not really sure why you're calling all these functions on blur and the multiple on clicks. Just do it in the one on click, call validate email, if that passes you move on to validate password and if that passes it makes the ajax call to actually check the details against the server.

Also avoid variable names like item5, errormsg6, to another developer that means nothing, and it won't to you in 6 months either. And don't tell people which element was wrong, ie "Incorrect password" just for security, just tell them their login details are wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* ----------------- Login Validations Global Variables -----------------   */
  var user_email2 = "";
  var user_emailajax2 = "";
  var user_password2 = "";
  var user_passwordajax2 = "";
  var emailformat = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
  /* ----------------- Define Validate Email */
  var validate_email_login = function() { 
    var email = $("#user_email2").val().toLowerCase();
      var errors = [];

    if (email.length < 6 || email.length > 50) {
        errors.push("Email : 6 - 50 Characters<br>");
    } 

    if (!emailformat.test(email)) {
      errors.push("Wrong Email Format");
    } 
    if( errors.length > 0 ) {
      $("#errormsg6").html(errors);
      return false;
    }
    $("#errormsg6").html();
    validate_password_login();
  }

  /* ----------------- Define Validate Password */
  var validate_password_login = function() {
    var item6 = $("#user_password2").val();

    if (item6.length < 8 || item6.length > 20) {
        $("#errormsg7").html("Password : 8-20 Characters");
        return false;
    }
    $("#errormsg7").html("");
    submitForm();
  }

  var submitForm = function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'validatelogin.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: $("#loginform").serialize(), 
      success: function(msg) {

        if(msg.email_check == 'true' && msg.password_check == 'true') {
            //do whatever it is you want to do on correct login here
        } else {
            $("#errormsg6").html("Your login details are incorrect, please check and try again");
        }
      }
    });
  }


  /* ----------------- Stop on Submit */
  $("#login").on('click', function() {
      errors = [];
    if(validate_email_login() == true) {
        alert("hi");
    }
  });
});
```

You can see the error validation on the jQuery end here: https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/3fhvpenr/

Comment: thanks for your answer but the requirement is on blur as well as on submit, this is because it is not just this form, entire website has various forms like registration, adding property, editing profile... and the masters want onblur and onsubmit both.... the masters do not know much about code, the want user experience.. check out gmail new email registration they have on blur and onsubmit

Comment: sure i understand this is a login and that is registration, but firming up the concept here can be applied there....

Comment: You can put the on blurs back, if you want, they'll still work, but multiple on blur handlers is just a pain in the ass. Either way having all those AJAX calls being fired and multiple on clicks on the same element is just not the way to do it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am going through it and seeing that my code needs substantial improvement... i am thankful to you...

Comment: Best of luck :)